# Proguard XmlRpc and Javac Parser

Tags: android, proguard, xmlrpcclient

I'm getting an error in the release version of my app.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getXMLReader()Le9/k; in class Ljavax/xml/parsers/SAXParser; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-libart.jar)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.util.SAXParsers.newXMLReader(SourceFile:9)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.newXMLReader(Unknown Source:0)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(SourceFile:1)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(SourceFile:35)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(SourceFile:4)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(SourceFile:28)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(SourceFile:2)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(SourceFile:5)
at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(SourceFile:4)
at l4.a0.p(SourceFile:135)
at k5.a.k(SourceFile:9)
at h8.c0.run(SourceFile:116)
at i8.c.run(SourceFile:24)
at n8.i.run(SourceFile:3)
at n8.a.run(SourceFile:94)
Suppressed: m8.e: [l1{Cancelling}@ca5e46a, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

How to solve it in proguard android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**
**proguard-rules.pro**

```
#xmlrpc
-keep class org.apache.xmlrpc.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.apache.xmlrpc.** { *;}

#javax
-keep class javax.xml.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class org.xml.sax.** { *;}

-dontnote javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser
```